Cambie el dns de mi dominio para mi nuevo hosting, han pasado 29 hrs y sigue mostrando la web antigua
El dia de ayer realice el cambio de nameservers de mi dominio alojado en godaddy, para apuntar mi dominio a mi nuevo hosting que es hostinger.
Pero han pasado 29 horas, y al ingresar desde otros dispositivos, sigue mostrando la web anterior alojada en el hosting anterior, pese a que ya realice una instalación de wordpress para ese dominio en mi nuevo hosting.
NOTA: NO migre el sitio, sino que solo cambie el nameservers del dominio para poder crear un nuevo sitio en el nuevo hosting para ese dominio.
¿Que podria estar pasando?
¿Cometi algun error?
Porfavor ayudenme.

Vete aquí y pon el nombre de tu dominio y comprueba la propagación de tus cambios: https://www.whatsmydns.net/

Ya vi y aparecen la mayoria con el check y el dns nuevo, solo el de tailandia aun aparece con X. :(
¿Podria ser porque falta ese?

No, si dices que todos estan con los nameservers nuevos entonces pueden ocurrir dos cosas: 1) No tienes bien los registros DNS en el nameserver nuevo y debes revisar su zona para comprobarlos. 2) Los nameservers que usas en tu conexión (de tu ISP) aún mantiene los nameservers antiguos de tu dominio y debes esperar a que se propagen allí. o bien prueba con otra conexión nueva (no otro dispositivo que use la misma conexion e ISP) o bien usa un proxy publico online para ver si desde alli llegas a tu nueva web mediante los nuevos nameservers

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!
Utilice un VPN para interntar ver si aparece mi web, y en otros paises si aparece mi nueva web, solo en mi pais aun aparece la antigua.
Espero sea solo de esperar.
Gracias

A ver, es raro que despues de tantas horas no se haya propagado aún... que no sea tambien un problema de cache de tu navegador.  Prueba intentando cargar alguna url de tu nuevo sitio que no exista en el anterior, para ver si llega.  Y si llega entonces el resto de páginas antiguas que aun ves podrian ser un problema de cache de tu navegador o ISP (si usan caches intermedios) y deberias refrescarlos de algun modo.  Tambien puedes probar haciendo un "ping midominio.com" desde un terminal o powershell y ver que IP te resuelve, para ver si aun apunta a la antigua.

Si, de hecho intente desde otros dispositivos y sigue mostrando la web antigua.
Haré la prueba que me indicas para comprobar la IP.
